# unix match multiple patterns in different lines

Tags: unix, search, grep

If I have a unix file contains the following:

```
aaaa12
bbbb34
ssss56
qqqq78
oooo90
aaaa01
bbbb23
```

I want to search for different patterns in different lines. in the above example if i want to print the lines that contain the two patterns (aaaa) and (bbbb) the output should be:

```
aaaa12
bbbb34
aaaa01
bbbb23
```

In the same order as the original file
What is the suitable unix command to do this

I tried egrep "aaaa | bbbb" but the output was:

```
aaaa12
aaaa01
bbbb34
bbbb23
```

Comment: From the input you have, this output seems impossible using `egrep`. `egrep` doesn't swap line numbers inside a file. What OS and `egrep` version are you using ? and How about the `awk` command I posted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you :

```
egrep "(aaaa|bbbb)" file
```

or you can use `awk` :

```
awk '/aaaa/||/bbbb/{print}' file
```

In both these cases, it searches for pattern "aaaa" or "bbbb" in the file and displays them as they are in the file. the brackets `()` in `egrep` is for grouping. More explanation on `egrep` regex can be found in here :

http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/egrep-regular-expression-syntax.html

Result is this :

```
$]egrep "(aaaa|bbbb)" file
 aaaa12
 bbbb34
 aaaa01
 bbbb23
```

- EDIT

OP probably wants the output in a single line rather than multiple lines. For that, you can do :

```
egrep "aaaa|bbbb" file | awk '{printf $0" "}'
```

OR

```
awk '/aaaa/||/bbbb/{printf $0" "}' file
```

Result :

```
aaaa12 bbbb34 aaaa01 bbbb23
```

Comment: I tried egrep but it displays the lines that match the first pattern followed by the lines match the second.. I want the output of the lines to be ordered as they in the file

Comment: Can u explain your above answer please

Comment: I have added what exactly I typed. It matches with your expected output that you've showed in your question...

Comment: Awk defaults to printing the whole line, so you don't need the `{print}`. And it supports alternation, so you can just use `/aaa|bbb/`

Comment: @Kevin You are right, but `print` adds to the verbosity needed for a beginner. OP may not know what is default in awk.

Comment: What are the two brackets ( and " for??

Comment: The brackets in egrep statement. . Is one of these brackets is enough??

Comment: @user2792748 added explanation to my answer.

Comment: The brackets are not really needed, `egrep "aaaa|bbbb"  file` works too (at least with my current gnu-win32 implementation)

Comment: @user2792748 did this work for you ?  You seem to be new SO, just so that you know, In SO, one should vote up or accept the answer if it works.

Comment: yeah am new in SO.. i tried egrep "aaaa|bbbb" but still the same problem the output for the first pattern lines and then the second pattern lines

Comment: @user2792748 what do you mean "first pattern lines and then the second pattern lines" ?

Comment: the output according to the example is:

Comment: aaaa12
aaaa01
bbbb34
bbbb23

Comment: @user2792748 Can you edit your question and put exactly what you are getting and what is your output ! In your question, you wanted it this way, correct ? Do you want all the matched pattern in a single line ?

Comment: @user2792748 I have modified my answer to include a command line to print the output in a single line. Is this what you want ?

Comment: @iamauser I have changed my question hope it is clear now.. please note the difference in the output int the lines order

Comment: It's working now.. I was using space between the | character and the patterns "aaaa | bbbb" so the output was not  correct . after trying "aaaa|bbbb" without space it is working

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
grep "aaaa\|bbbb" file
```

now it really works.

Comment: You need to make it an ERE (`-E` or `-r`, depending on your implementation) or use `\|`.

Comment: Yep, of course, you are right. Did not have a version of grep installed on my current notebook. Just checked it and will edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest form for that is to use two expressions with -e:

```
egrep -e aaaa -e bbbb file
fgrep -e aaaa -e bbbb file
```

Output:

```
aaaa12
bbbb34
aaaa01
bbbb23
```